# Conditional Tag Based on Age of Post

Tags: conditional-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add inline HTML to posts published within last 24hrs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64170/add-inline-html-to-posts-published-within-last-24hrs)

I've been searching through the codex and Google and cannot not find a conditional tag based on age of post.

I'm looking to display a graphic overlay on top of a featured image if the post is less than three days old, for example.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$today = date('r');
$articledate = get_the_time('r');
$difference = round((strtotime($today) - strtotime($articledate))/(24*60*60),0);
if ($difference >= 3) { ?>
this is a three day old post
<?php } ?>
```

the 3 in if ($difference >= 3) { ?> is 3 days old, you can change that to whatever you want. How I could do it, is add a css class to include the image.